# Security monitoring in the cloud?

Tags: denial-of-service, cloud-computing, detection, monitoring

I am working for a company which works with PHI, HIPAA, PCI and other highest sensitivity data. Their current security architecture uses hardware network monitoring tools to monitor the network connections between servers to detect security incidents and other abnormal traffic. They are looking to migrate their applications to the various cloud providers and are wondering how to do something similar there. Are there ways to guarantee network links are exclusively used only by specified hosts or components in the cloud? How would we monitor these connections, or can we only monitor requests coming in to our servers or applications? Is it just a case of trusting the provider's security claims and blaming them if there is a breach? Or can we maintain responsibility and control and should we? What are some other cloud specific security challenges that we might not be considering and how do we mitigate those? Thank you for any good info or references.

Answer (score 2):

**Are there ways to guarantee network links are exclusively used only by specified hosts or components in the cloud?**

This depends on your cloud provider. Most cloud providers will allow this if for instance you want  them to build a full private cloud for them. If you are looking for this option to provide security in terms of availability by offering connectivity from multiple data centers, then yes you could ask them. But do note this comes with a price tag.

**How would we monitor these connections, or can we only monitor requests coming in to our servers or applications?**

You could opt to procure IDS/IPS or WAF systems (virtual or physical) to monitor these lines. Note that in the end you are working with a cloud provider to save cost on maintenance or provide scalability, so most likely the cloud provider will have access to it

**Is it just a case of trusting the provider's security claims and blaming them if there is a breach?**

Probably they have their ass covered with regard to such demands and they will put blame on you.

**What are some other cloud specific security challenges that we might not be considering and how do we mitigate those?**

The most issues I see in the real world is with regard to hosting information in certain countries. For instance banking information from Switzerland and Luxembourg can only be hosted in those respective countries and no where else. The one fabulous thing about cloud computing is that you can have geographical failover, which means distributing your data across countries. So if you have requirements in place that require you to not distribute information to certain countries (e.g. in Europe many companies do not want to have their information sent to datacenters in the US) than you need to make those clear as well to your hosting provider.

**Finally I would like to add these comments:**

First you need to understand *why* you want to move things to the cloud. Is this for more flexible computing, less hardware maintenance, reduced costs for operating a data center, etc... or is it because someone saw that the "cloud" (did you know cloud can be replaced with just "somewhere on the internet") is cool and decided to move everything there because he heard other people were doing it.

If you do require flexible computing and scalability it might make more sense to build your own cloud infrastructure so you have full control of your environment.

Many people believe cloud computing is about automagically getting cost reduction by not having to host your own hardware, but it's at its core not different from using a managed hosting provider.

Cloud computing at its core is about scalability, flexibility and availability. If you require these properties it makes sense to move your applications into a cloud environment, if you don't then you need to reconsider.

Comment: Thank you for your very well thought out feedback! I have a lot of questions, but first thing just wanted to thank you and also to say that as I was considering my advice to this company I was considering just saying "don't move to the cloud" lol!

Has anyone said yet that cloud providers are _more_ secure than what an enterprise can do on their own?

Comment: they have not and most of the time the more secure is true about the cloud provider's backend systems rather than improving the security for the end user.

Comment: "Probably they have their ass covered with regard to such demands and they will put blame on you." - This.  This is important.  Unless they specifically, in writing, and in the format required in each jurisdiction you can be held accountable in specifically accept all liability for any breaches (and they won't), then you can bet their lawyers have covered such an essential risk in their business plan.  They may have spent more on legal advice there than you are on your cloud hosting.

Comment: Both Azure and AWS advertize HIPAA / PCI compliance on their websites. Doesn't this mean they take the responsibility for breaches?

I still understand that if a company dealing with health or financial info experiences a breach, their reputation would be affected. Saying "We trusted Amazon/Microsoft" isn't really a response the customers would appreciate.

Comment: Only way to check this is to take it into a contract

Comment: @LucasKauffman - Regarding private clouds - From your response I assume both Azure and Amazon offer this premium service. How is this different from just hiring a 3rd party company to set up your data center? Also, doesn't it negate the typical benefits of cloud hosting?

Comment: @LucasKauffman - Regarding IPS / IDS / WAF in the cloud. Can you go into more detail about how Azure / AWS support this? Are there specific vendors they support or do they support all vendors? IPS is often "inline" and when the "lines" are abstracted and shared as in a cloud environment I would think this might not be as effective, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @LucasKauffman - My current leaning is to tell them to heavily use encryption, perhaps even encrypt at the client so that any data stored in the cloud is totally useless say if an Amazon or MS employee decided to mess around. This might have a slight performance impact on the client though, and then we add the complexity of certificate management for potentially millions of clients. What do you think of this idea?

Comment: @LucasKauffman - And with regards to their desire to detect anomalous traffic my inclination is to tell them not to worry so much about it since the data is encrypted, and to say it is more of a cost issue which we can resolve with the cloud billing departments if we get charged exorbitant rates for anomalous traffic spikes and that non-real-time logs and monitoring is good enough for us to be able to double check our bill. Again, would like your opinion on this. Do we need IPS / WAF in the cloud? Are we still vulnerable? Possibly to DOS attack?

Comment: @LucasKauffman - I'm a little confused because IPS / WAF systems are usually used on incoming traffic from public networks, not traffic between servers within the data center, but this is what I was told to investigate. Traffic for example between a web and database server.

Comment: Normally ips are put between each network zone and not only the DMZ. Amazon and azure are different in the way they can offer you more robustness and normally also cheaper rates. Encryption is a good thing, but in general you want to avoid encryption when it comes into a waf or ips. Anomaly detection is still a must, encryption is a preventive control, an ids is a detective control. You want several controls.